# Color picker ignoring set value

Tags: javascript

I'm unable to set the value of my color picker using the syntax:

```
color_picker.value = button_color
```

I created this snippet to show my attempt, but I also can't seem to figure out why in this snippet, button_color is returning an empty string instead of the background color of the button.

```
<button id="button_1">Button</button>
<input type="color" id="color_picker"/>
```

```
#button_1 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```
const button_1 = document.getElementById('button_1')
const color_picker = document.getElementById('color_picker')

let button_color = button_1.style.backgroundColor
console.log('button_color is ', button_color)
color_picker.value = button_color
console.log('showColorPickerButtons color picker value is ', color_picker.value)
color_picker.oninput = () => {
        let color = color_picker.value
        changeButtonsColor(color)
    }
    
function changeButtonsColor(color) {
    console.log(color)
    let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('button')
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].style.backgroundColor = color
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`backgroundColor` is an empty string because you are acessing the `style` prop of the element.

As you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) the `style` prop only returns values that are defined **inline**.

If you want to get the button's background color to use on the color input, you need to use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Replace by

```js
let button_color = getComputedStyle(button_1, null).getPropertyValue("background-color")
```

Then, since the input won't accept an rgb value you'll need to convert it to hex.

```js
const rgba2hex = (rgba) => `#${rgba.match(/^rgba?\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)(?:,\s*(\d+\.{0,1}\d*))?\)$/).slice(1).map((n, i) => (i === 3 ? Math.round(parseFloat(n) * 255) : parseFloat(n)).toString(16).padStart(2, '0').replace('NaN', '')).join('')}`
```

Full code for initial color in input using button's background color:

```js
const button_1 = document.getElementById('button_1')
console.log("b", button_1)
const color_picker = document.getElementById('color_picker')

let button_color = getComputedStyle(button_1, null).getPropertyValue("background-color")
console.log('button_color is ', button_color)
const rgba2hex = (rgba) => `#${rgba.match(/^rgba?\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)(?:,\s*(\d+\.{0,1}\d*))?\)$/).slice(1).map((n, i) => (i === 3 ? Math.round(parseFloat(n) * 255) : parseFloat(n)).toString(16).padStart(2, '0').replace('NaN', '')).join('')}`
const hexColor = rgba2hex(button_color);
color_picker.value = hexColor;
console.log('showColorPickerButtons color picker value is ', color_picker.value)
color_picker.oninput = () => {
        let color = color_picker.value
        changeButtonsColor(color)
    }
    
function changeButtonsColor(color) {
    console.log(color)
    let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('button')
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].style.backgroundColor = color
    }
}
```

```css
#button_1 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<button id="button_1">Button</button>
<input type="color" id="color_picker"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect. I have an almost identical function that changes the color of the HTML body's background, and using window.getComputedStyle(body).getPropertyValue('background-color') returns "body not defined." Is that because body is not an actual element? Is there a way around that?

Comment: @CrystalGarnet `getComputedStyle` expects an element as the first argument, how are you setting the `body` variable ? https://codepen.io/nip10/pen/eYWeqgr

Comment: Oh that was my mistake, I wasn't defining the body properly using getElementsByTagName. It's working perfectly now, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This turned out to be more complex than I thought. I wasn't able to extract the background color at page load. So, I went with window.getComputedStyle - which returned an RGB value. **The color picker only accepts full 7-character hex values**, so I used a helper function to convert the rgb to hex and walla, it works!

The event listener has a single function argument `event`, which I am referring to as `e` below. The caller of the listener (the color picker) is the `target`, so getting the value is `e.target.value`. We then just apply that to the button's background-color style.

```js
const rgba2hex = (rgba) => `#${rgba.match(/^rgba?\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)(?:,\s*(\d+\.{0,1}\d*))?\)$/).slice(1).map((n, i) => (i === 3 ? Math.round(parseFloat(n) * 255) : parseFloat(n)).toString(16).padStart(2, '0').replace('NaN', '')).join('')}`
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let button = document.querySelector('#button_1');
  let bg = window.getComputedStyle(button, null).getPropertyValue('background-color');
  document.querySelector('#color_picker').value = rgba2hex(bg)
  document.querySelector('#color_picker').addEventListener('input', e => {
    button.style.backgroundColor = e.target.value
  })
})
```

```css
#button_1 {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<button id="button_1">Button</button>
<input type="color" id="color_picker" value="" />
```